# Help with Bulk Metadata Updates

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, managed-metadata, import

I'm having the following conundrum with a bulk update of Metadata. But first, some background...

I have a library of about 2000 letters that currently live on a shared drive. We're migrating those to SharePoint so we can track changes and make them available as read-only reference documents for our CSRs. Each letter on the shared drive has a header paragraph that was manually added before it was stored. The header looks like this:

```
Service Guide - WI
Description: Explains payment and billing options
Reference Number: 1298
Replaces brochure: N/A
Special Conditions: N/A
States Applicable: WI & MI
How Generated: This document is for viewing purposes only
When Generated: Consultant can mail through XXXX
Owner: Sxxxx Xxxxx
Last change date: Sept. 21, 2010
```

I've created a delimited text file containing all the data values (extracted by choosing a substring of 'stuff after the colon' when the line startsWith), but now, I'm getting data mismatches when I try to paste that data into SharePoint's datasheet view of my library.

For instance, I've got a StatesApplicable column defined as two checkboxes, WI and MI, and the ability to check one or both. Pasting the string "WI", "MI" or "MI; WI" results in a mismatch--I suspect that in a battle between String vs. SP checkbox, SP wins.

Any suggestions about a good way to go about importing these data values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"You can view a sample import file by clicking View a sample import file from the properties pane of a managed metadata service in the Term Store Management Tool. The simplest way to create an import file for your term set is to use the sample import file as a template. Save the sample import file; delete everything except the first row. Then add more rows to represent your term set and terms."`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424396.aspx

<strike>That was going to be my suggestion, but I was still trying to find an example via Google without much luck.</strike>

Just realized ^ was dumb. You're trying to import into the term store. The "data mismatch" is caused by the fact that you have too many values on the line (I think). Try "MI, WI" instead of "MI", "WI".